# Get information from a model using unrelated field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have these two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class D(models.Model):
   code=models.IntegerField()
```

the code field can have a number that exists in model A but it cant be related due to other factors. But what I want know is to list items from A whose value is the same with code

```
items=D.objects.values('code__name')
```

would work but since they are not related nor can be related, how can I handle that?

Comment: code field can have a number that exists in model A -- what do you mean? code == pk in model A?

Comment: @BearBrown Yes it holds number that exist in model A

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Subquery() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) in **Django 1.11** or newer.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

code_subquery = A.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('code'))
qs = D.objects.annotate(code_name=Subquery(code_subquery.values('name')))
```

The output of `qs` is a queryset of objects `D` with an added field `code_name`.

---

**Footnotes:**

It is compiled to a very similar SQL (like the Bear Brown's solution with "extra" method, but without disadvantages of his solution, see there):

```
SELECT app_d.id, app_d.code,
       (SELECT U0.name FROM app_a U0 WHERE U0.id = (app_d.code)) AS code_name
FROM app_d
```

If a dictionary output is required it can be converted by `.values()` finally. It can work like a left join i.e. if the pseudo related field allows null (`code = models.IntegerField(none=True)`) then the objects D are not restricted and the output code_name value could be None. A feature of Subquery is that it returns only one field expression must be eventually repeated for another fields. (That is similar to `extra(select={...: "SELECT ..."})`, but thanks to object syntax it can be more readable customized than an explicit SQL.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [django extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra), replace `YOUAPP` on your real app name

```
D.objects.extra(select={'a_name': 'select name from YOUAPP_a where id=code'}).values('a_name')
#                                          Replace YOUAPP^^^^^
```

Comment: +1: because the `.extra()` method was necessary not long ago before Django 1.11, but it is associated with a security warning and a note "Use this method as a last resort."
 (docs). My experience is that it had many unexpected limitations and consequences, including "Replace YOUAPP". I feel new query expression classes very friendly.

Comment: If you use `.values('a_name')` then the result has only that field. It is useless. (Can be fixed easily many ways. Yes, sometimes must be field names repeated in values.) That is what I meant that the rules how to use the extra() method correctly are not easy to remember even after a long experience.